# Replacing a custom tag to <br>

Tags: jquery

I'm doing an experiment... and I wan to replace a custom tag named `<w>` to `<br>`, with all the other custom tags, it works right, except with `<br>`.

Look, here's my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("w").replaceWith('<br />');
    $("elp").wrap("<h1></h1>");
  });
});
</script>
```

And in html i have:

```
<elp>Hello world</elp>
    <w>
<elp>Hola Mundo</elp>
```

thank you.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYb6n/)

Comment: Did you try `.replace("something", "<br />")`

Comment: the elp replacement isn't working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/HVyek/

Comment: My mistake, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/HVyek/1/

Comment: @WillemEllis [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYb6n/)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Noope, but i'm trying... and it works so right!

Comment: oh... but if i put < w > more than one time.. it doesn't work

Comment: @huMptyduMpty .replace works if i put $(document).replace("<w>", "<br />")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close your `<w>`:

```
<elp>Hello world</elp>
<w></w>
<elp>Hola Mundo</elp>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/64nKW/

Comment: But can i do it without close <w>?

Comment: @Darkness It's not possible, as browsers do not recognize it as a self closing tag. Maybe it is possible by adding your own DTD.

Comment: But what about the text in the bottom area?

Comment: I guess it's the only way <w></w>

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not closed your w tag....

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('<w>').replaceWith('<br>');
    $("elp").wrap("<h1></h1>");
  });
```

that seems to work for me..

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/9YUsw/2/

Comment: Mmm... no, it only changed the text.

Comment: Yes... Finally! :DDD !!

Comment: @SamWard Actually it does not work. The line breaks are a result of `<h1>` being a block element.

Comment: Yes, i think the only way is write <w></w>